# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the

Tags: javascript, php, json, sockets

I have problems when y try parse my JSON and i can't solve.

here i catch... in my file js

```
var JSONdata    = JSON.parse(message); //parseo la informacion
// console.log(JSONdata);
  nombre = JSONdata[0].nombre;
  nit = JSONdata[0].nit;
  funcionario = JSONdata[0].funcionario;
  nro_radicado = JSONdata[0].nro_radicado;
  nrosolicitud = JSONdata[0].nrosolicitud;
  consulta = JSONdata[0].consulta;
  hora = JSONdata[0].hora;
```

my file that y use ajax for conection... whit function `send(data)` i send info to my js

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "quotes_controller.php",
        data: "fecha_cita="+fecha_cita+"&atendio="+atendio+"&nombre="+nombre+"&apellido="+apellido+"&LISTA="+LISTA+"&nroradicado="+nroradicado+"&nrosolicitud="+nrosolicitud,
        dataType:"html",
        success: function(data) 
        {///// here sen data response
          send(data);// array JSON
/////////////////////////////////////
          window.location.href = 'index.php'
        },
        error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
            alert('algo fallo...');
            console.log(jqXHR);
        }
        });
```

and my file php that make the JSON before insert into BD

```
$arrayjson = array();
$arrayjson[] = array(
                    'nit'          => '1223344',//nit del solicitante
                    'nombre'       => 'el nombre',// nombres concatenados 
                    'funcionario'  => $_POST['atendio'],//quien atiende
                    'nro_radicado' => $nro_radicado,//numero de radicado
                    'nrosolicitud' => $_POST['nrosolicitud'],// numero de solicitud
                    'consulta'     => 'APORTAR PLANOS',//tipo de consulta que se realiza
                    'hora'         => $hora//hora de agendamiento
);

echo json_encode($arrayjson);
```

the `concole.log(message);` is...

```
[{"nit":"1223344","nombre":"el nombre","funcionario":"10","nro_radicado":"","nrosolicitud":"","consulta":"APORTAR PLANOS","hora":"11:04:47"}]
```

all dates hace values... i don't know what happend.. please help me

Comment: Can you show  `console.log(message)` before parsing?

Comment: thanks for reply me.... i add the console.log

Comment: Okay.. the data is correct, the only thing I can think of is : the console log eavalutaes lazily, when do you do your parsing? Are waiting for the `async` call to be over and then parse ?

Comment: not, first async and with these response send to my function.

Comment: 1) ajax -> php make Json ->response from ajax send(data) -> file js -> i try catch data but i can't :(

Comment: On your ajax call you are specifying the data type to be HTML, try changing it to JSON `dataType: 'json'`